# What search operator will limit search results to content in a specific language?

Tags: google-search, search-operators

I'm using Google Search and want to limit results to pages written in a language I specify.

There is a similar question [How to restrict a Google search to results of a specific language?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16047/how-to-restrict-a-google-search-to-results-of-a-specific-language/80416) that has [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/80416/262677), however I don't have access to the URL in order to edit it in my setup.

For example, to specify search results to pages written in German the URL can be modified using the `lr` parameter (eg. `lr=lang_de`) but I've tried all possible combinations of `lr=lang_de` in the actual search box both with and without the `lr` parameter without success.

How can I specify the language using an operator in the field?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Read the help article about the Language Filter : [Use Results Language Filter for Google Search](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/13485060?hl=en) and [How Google determines the language of search results](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/13511324?hl=en).

---

There is no search operator to write in the search box to set the language of the results. Unfortunately, Google has made harder to find the currently supported functions, symbols and search operators. See [my answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/172397/88163) to [Where to find a list of Google search operators?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/122235/88163) for details.

Because there is no search operator, the alternatives to filter search results for a specific language without editing the URL in the [address bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_bar) / omnibox, you might

1. Use the **Language Filter**.

   - On the results page, click Tools, then select the language.
   - If the language options are not shown, or the language you are looking for is not listed, click Settings, then Languages. Alternatively, go to https://www.google.com/preferences.
2. Use **Advanced Search**
3. Write the URLs as bookmarks
4. Write the URLs using an application that allows you to create hyperlinks, like a word processor, spreadsheet, notebook, or quick notes like Google Keep.
5. Add a custom search engine to your web browser. See [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/36266/88163) to [How to restrict a Google search to results of a specific language?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/16047/88163).

Below the line, I will focus on using **Advanced Search**.

---

## Advanced Search

To use **Advanced Search** from the Google homepage

1. Go to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com).
2. Click on Settings.
   *This will open a dropdown menu*.
3. Then click **Advanced Search**.

To open **Advanced Search** directly

1. Go to https://www.google.com/advanced_search.

To open **Advanced Search** from the Google search results

1. Click Settings (the cog / gear button)
   *This will open a dropdown menu*.
2. If needed, scroll down until you find **Advanced Search**, then click **Advanced Search**.

Once you are on the **Advanced Search** page

1. Fill the fields according to what you need to search.
2. If needed, scroll down until you find the section **Then narrow your results by...**, and select the language.
   *In this case, **German**.*

   > [image: Then narrow your results by...]
3. Click the **Advanced Search** button.

## Related

### Related Help Articles

#### Featured

- [Use Results Language Filter for Google Search](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/13485060?hl=en).
- [How Google determines the language of search results](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/13511324?hl=en).

#### Other

- [Refine Google searches](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en).
- [Do an Advanced Search on Google](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/35890?hl=en).

### Questions

- [Setting Google results to stay in a language, regardless of location](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/14435/88163)
- [How to restrict a Google search to results of a specific language?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/16047/88163)
- [How can I make Google do one-shot searches in a specific language only?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/27918/88163)

Comment: This a good answer. I would move it from here to the [duplicate target](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16047/how-to-restrict-a-google-search-to-results-of-a-specific-language).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149083/discussion-on-answer-by-ruben-what-search-operator-will-limit-search-results-to); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.